# My Apple Macbook Pro (M1) keeps crashing. A glitchy pink screen appears, then it restarts. What is happening here?

Tags: mac, drivers, osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion, kernel

I have provided the error log at the bottom. This is the 4th time this has happened to me. I am doing very light tasks like browsing and typing, when all of the sudden a glitchy pink screen appears and my Mac completely crashes. I've seen this happening with other people too, and it only seems to be the M1 chips doing this.

Here is the error log:

```
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xfffffe0026f45798): "dart-disp0 (0xfffffe233315c000): SMMU(SMMU) error: SID 0 PTE invalid exception on read with DVA 0x6a0000 (TTBR 0 SEG 0 PTE 0x1a8) ERROR_STATUS 0x80000004 TIME 0x62ef26f40ce3 TTE 0 AXI_ID 0)"
Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x6
OS release type: User
OS version: 20F71
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 20.5.0: Sat May  8 05:10:31 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.121.3~9/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101
Fileset Kernelcache UUID: FB10CC0AB8BAC020BC47A50D64476F11
Kernel UUID: 07259C53-9EF7-32FF-821D-8F28A5985DFA
iBoot version: iBoot-6723.120.36
secure boot?: YES
Paniclog version: 13
KernelCache slide: 0x000000001dd6c000
KernelCache base:  0xfffffe0024d70000
Kernel slide:      0x000000001e8b4000
Kernel text base:  0xfffffe00258b8000
Kernel text exec base:  0xfffffe0025984000
mach_absolute_time: 0x25fda0d71e7
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x6156fdb1 0x0007113f
  Sleep   : 0x615a6606 0x00075536
  Wake    : 0x615a6629 0x000e4078
  Calendar: 0x615a6d80 0x0002f919

CORE 0 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0025af66f4
CORE 1 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0025af5240
CORE 2 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0025af66f4
CORE 3 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0025af66f4
CORE 4 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0025af66f8
CORE 5 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0025af66f8
CORE 6 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0025af66f8
CORE 7 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0025af66f8
Panicked task 0xfffffe166897bac8: 4965 pages, 22 threads: pid 140: WindowServer
Panicked thread: 0xfffffe16689a8cc0, backtrace: 0xfffffe306a4474f0, tid: 898800
          lr: 0xfffffe00259d2be4  fp: 0xfffffe306a447560
          lr: 0xfffffe00259d29c8  fp: 0xfffffe306a4475d0
          lr: 0xfffffe0025afba70  fp: 0xfffffe306a4475f0
          lr: 0xfffffe0025aed2b8  fp: 0xfffffe306a4476a0
          lr: 0xfffffe002598b7e8  fp: 0xfffffe306a4476b0
          lr: 0xfffffe00259d2658  fp: 0xfffffe306a447a40
          lr: 0xfffffe00259d2658  fp: 0xfffffe306a447ab0
          lr: 0xfffffe00261843e8  fp: 0xfffffe306a447ad0
          lr: 0xfffffe0026f45798  fp: 0xfffffe306a447d40
          lr: 0xfffffe0026f45270  fp: 0xfffffe306a447dd0
          lr: 0xfffffe0026f44a5c  fp: 0xfffffe306a447e80
          lr: 0xfffffe00260b1ec0  fp: 0xfffffe306a447ec0
          lr: 0xfffffe00260e7dc0  fp: 0xfffffe306a447f20
          lr: 0xfffffe0026af28c8  fp: 0xfffffe306a447fb0
          lr: 0xfffffe00260d89e0  fp: 0xfffffe306a447fc0
          lr: 0xfffffe0025aefce0  fp: 0xfffffe306a447fe0
          lr: 0xfffffe002598b85c  fp: 0xfffffe306a447ff0
          lr: 0xfffffe0025ae9f60  fp: 0xfffffe402370bb20
          lr: 0xfffffe00259b0a4c  fp: 0xfffffe402370bc60
          lr: 0xfffffe00259b1cb4  fp: 0xfffffe402370bcc0
          lr: 0xfffffe00259c87c4  fp: 0xfffffe402370bd70
          lr: 0xfffffe0025ae1c40  fp: 0xfffffe402370be40
          lr: 0xfffffe0025aed334  fp: 0xfffffe402370bef0
          lr: 0xfffffe002598b7e8  fp: 0xfffffe402370bf00
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleT8020DART(1.0)[F6E1E036-504F-3FDF-B83B-6732226FF906]@0xfffffe0026f40000->0xfffffe0026f47fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform(1.0.2)[F784412E-33CC-3859-B0CB-D0A62C9E26CB]@0xfffffe00262e0000->0xfffffe002632ffff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.IODARTFamily(1)[55309CB3-D624-3B9B-962A-E82571B663FC]@0xfffffe0027a18000->0xfffffe0027a2bfff
         com.apple.driver.AppleInterruptController(1.0d1)[E7931F7A-8581-32B7-8A33-394B279B926C]@0xfffffe0026af0000->0xfffffe0026af3fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform(1.0.2)[F784412E-33CC-3859-B0CB-D0A62C9E26CB]@0xfffffe00262e0000->0xfffffe002632ffff

last started kext at 496139764: com.apple.driver.AppleActuatorDriver    4440.3 (addr 0xfffffe0024f2c000, size 16384)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 4050.1
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.fileutil  20.036.15
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    8.0.5d7
com.apple.driver.AppleBiometricServices 1
com.apple.driver.BCMWLANFirmware4378.Hashstore  1
com.apple.driver.CoreKDL    1
com.apple.driver.SEPHibernation 1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.ReadWriteDiskImage  493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.UDIFDiskImage   493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.RAMBackingStore 493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.FileBackingStore    493.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  1677.120.9
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBDeviceNCM  5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 4.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleALSColorSensor    1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleAOPVoiceTrigger   11.5
com.apple.driver.ApplePMP   1
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.driver.ApplePMPFirmware   1
com.apple.nke.l2tp  1.9
com.apple.filesystems.tmpfs 1
com.apple.IOTextEncryptionFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  556.100.11
com.apple.security.BootPolicy   1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartIO2  1
com.apple.AppleEmbeddedSimpleSPINORFlasher  1
com.apple.driver.AppleDPDisplayTCON 1
com.apple.driver.AppleCS42L83Audio  442.26
com.apple.driver.AppleSPMIPMU   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleTAS5770LAmp   442.26
com.apple.driver.AppleSummitLCD 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleT8020SOCTuner 1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103CLPCv3   1
com.apple.AGXG13G   173.28.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAVD   381
com.apple.driver.AppleAVE2  401.73.3
com.apple.driver.AppleJPEGDriver    4.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileDispH13G-DCP    140.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostT8103  1
com.apple.driver.AudioDMAController-T8103   1.60.5
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8960XNCO   1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PMGR 1
com.apple.driver.AppleS8000AES  1
com.apple.driver.AppleS8000DWI  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8960XWatchDogTimer 1
com.apple.driver.AppleInterruptController   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothModule   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSamsungSerial 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe   1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8020DART 1
com.apple.driver.AppleSynopsysMIPIDSI   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8920XPWM   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8940XI2C   1.0.0d2
com.apple.driver.AppleSPIMC 1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8101 1
com.apple.driver.AppleM68Buttons    1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBUserHCI    1
com.apple.iokit.IOKitRegistryCompatibility  1
com.apple.iokit.EndpointSecurity    1
com.apple.driver.AppleDiskImages2   1
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 2.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   311
com.apple.kec.InvalidateHmac    1
com.apple.driver.AppleActuatorDriver    4440.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  4440.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 4050.1
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   8.0.5d7
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   224
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 940.4
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   985.2
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMesaSEPDriver 100.99
com.apple.iokit.IOBiometricFamily   1
com.apple.driver.AppleTrustedAccessory  1
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPHDCPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.AppleSEPGenericTransfer 1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.KernelBacked    493.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHostControllerPCIeTransport 8.0.5d7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  8.0.5d7
com.apple.driver.AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl  1
com.apple.driver.AppleConvergedPCI  1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothDebug    1
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBTM   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    8.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    8.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltUSBDownAdapter 1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 4.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAOPAudio  16.2
com.apple.nke.ppp   1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransportSPI   4400.35
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransport  4400.35
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    4400.35
com.apple.AGXFirmwareKextG13GRTBuddy    173.28.1
com.apple.AGXFirmwareKextRTBuddy64  173.28.1
com.apple.driver.AppleDCPDPTXProxy  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.DCPDPFamilyProxy   1
com.apple.driver.AppleStockholmControl  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBSDKextStarter    3
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleDiagnosticDataAccessReadOnly  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSPU   1
com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily    2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleNANDConfigAccess  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPM   3.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleCSEmbeddedAudio   442.26
com.apple.driver.AppleDialogPMU 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudio 442.26
com.apple.iokit.AppleARMIISAudio    80.34.1
com.apple.driver.ApplePassthroughPPM    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOGPUFamily 21.11
com.apple.driver.AppleH11ANEInterface   4.75.0
com.apple.driver.AppleH13CameraInterface    3.55.0
com.apple.driver.AppleH10PearlCameraInterface   16.15.1
com.apple.driver.DCPAVFamilyProxy   1
com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily-DCP  343.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDCP   1
com.apple.driver.AppleFirmwareKit   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSPMI  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXDCIARM    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXDCI   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBDeviceFamily   2.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIARM    1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedUSBHost   1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103TypeCPhy 1
com.apple.driver.AppleSART  1
com.apple.driver.ApplePMGR  1
com.apple.driver.watchdog   1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDisplayCrossbar   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IODisplayPortFamily 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleTypeCPhy  1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    7.2.8
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PCIeC    1
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 9.3.2
com.apple.driver.ApplePIODMA    1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PCIe 1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothDebugService 1
com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANCore   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211FamilyV2 1200.12.2b1
com.apple.driver.IOImageLoader  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileDispH13G-DFR    140.0
com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily  343.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCA2-T8103    540.10
com.apple.driver.AppleGPIOICController  1.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFireStormErrorHandler 1
com.apple.driver.AppleMultiFunctionManager  1
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedPCIE  1
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileApNonce 1
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    985.2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 493.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    585.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   8.0.5d7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothPacketLogger 8.0.5d7
com.apple.driver.FairPlayIOKit  68.7.1
com.apple.iokit.CoreAnalyticsFamily 1
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPKeyStore   2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    511.120.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  184.121.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   436.121.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   436.121.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIPAppender    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.RTBuddy    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedTempSensor    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleARMPMU    1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAccessoryManager  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOnboardSerial 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSkywalkFamily 1
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleA7IOP 1.0.2
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.driver.AppleBiometricSensor   2
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.AUC   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAVFamily  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHDCPFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOCECFamily 1
com.apple.iokit.IOAudio2Family  1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudioLibs 1.17
com.apple.driver.AppleFirmwareUpdateKext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleM2ScalerCSCDriver 265.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   290.8.1
com.apple.driver.IODARTFamily   1
com.apple.security.quarantine   4
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.kext.CoreTrust    1
com.apple.security.AppleImage4  3.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOCryptoAcceleratorFamily   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform   1.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  47
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    11.1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1



** Stackshot Succeeded ** Bytes Traced 409360 (Uncompressed 1049152) **
```

Comment: [Seems pretty related](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/421608/macbook-air-m1-repeated-kernel-panics-because-of-display-external-hub) If it is caused by a peripheral, I would check if there's any way to update the one that's causing the issue and make sure your OS is fully up to date.

Answer (score 0):

My though is exactly update your mac to the newest operating system sometimes that helps. As for the pink screen it could be something with the GPU or iGPU